# Short-circuit a flatMap if an exception occurs

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I have a `flatMap` that runs a series of HTTP calls to register a user, retrieve their profile, and some other things.  I would like to notify `onError` in my `subscription` with a particular error message depending on which stage of the `flatMap` an error occurs.  Maybe the registration was successful, but retrieving the created profile was not.  How could I accomplish this such that my `flatMap` stops all the subsequent calls once an error happens?

Here is some pseudocode of my `Observable` and `Subscription`:

```
Retrofit.registerUser()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap({
            return Retrofit.authenticate();
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap({
            return Retrofit.retrieveProfile() 
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap({
            return Retrofit.retrieveOtherStuff()
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Action1 {

        }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
          // I would like to display the error to my user here
        }));
```

Comment: Do you create several observables or just one? It would be great if you show your code.

Comment: @Foxinsocks Just one.  Thanks, pseudocode added.

Comment: @mattblang, ooops, sorry for the downvote. Probably pressed it accidentally while browsing stackoverflow from a mobile phone. Could you please edit your question so I can take the downvote back? (stackoverflow allows to revote only when question changes)

Comment: @VladimirMironov Haha, NP!  Question edited.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do it:

1. Using `doOnError` operator:

   ```
   Retrofit.registerUser()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .doOnError(error -> {
           showRegistrationFailedError(error);
       })
       .flatMap({
           return Retrofit.authenticate().doOnError(error -> {
               showAuthenticationFailedError(error);
           });
       })
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(new Action1 {

       }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
         // do nothing here. all errors are already handled in doOnError methods
       }));
   ```
2. Using `onErrorResumeNext` operator:

   ```
   Retrofit.registerUser()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
           return Observable.error(new RegistrationFailedException(error));
       })
       .flatMap({
           return Retrofit.authenticate().onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
               return Observable.error(new AuthenticationFailedException(error))
           });
       })
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(value -> {

       }, error -> {
           if (error instanceof RegistrationFailedException) {
               showRegistrationFailedError(error);
           }

           if (error instanceof AuthenticationFailedException) {
               showAuthenticationFailedError(error);   
           }
       }));
   ```

Comment: I was using your first suggestion originally, but an exception in the first `Observable` causes every `doOnError` in the `flatMap` chain to trigger.

Comment: Also the second method does the same thing, it throws the `onErrorResumeNext` exception at every stage of the `flatMap`.  I'm left wondering if I am doing something incorrectly here.